# With Framework V2, trying to get an instance of EntityManagerFactory to be used with endpoint gives java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

Uploading my backend to app engine servers after updating my project with Google cloud Framework V2 gives me a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when i try to access to some instance of EntityManagerFactory.

Indeed I have a class EMF that i call :

```
 public final class EMF {

 private static final EntityManagerFactory emfInstance = Persistence
    .createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

 private EMF() {
 }

 public static EntityManagerFactory get() {
return emfInstance;
 }

 }`
```

On app engine V1 everything was fine. Any clues?

Edit 3 (in answer to Mickael request), Log on App Engine : (all the servlet or endpoints which call EntityManagerFactory throw the same exception)

```
> 
2017-10-10 (15:09:52.925)
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.example.app.EMF
at com.example.app.CustomContactImageEndpoint.getEntityManager(CustomContactImageEndpoint.java:585)
at com.example.app.CustomContactImageEndpoint.findContactImagesMoment(CustomContactImageEndpoint.java:79)
at com.example.app.ContactImageServlet.doGetImpl(ContactImageServlet.java:33)
at com.example.app.feed2.WPHttpServlet.doGet(WPHttpServlet.java:41)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:58)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:257)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:680)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:642)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:612)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:297)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:320)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:312)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:274)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
request_id: "59dcc69f00ff0dc24abd77a6f40001737e6d6773746166663839000132000100"
timestamp: "2017-10-10T13:09:52.925Z"
```

My web.xml has been changed to invoke EndpointsServlet in V2 instead of SystemServiceServlet of V1 and Client endpoint also have been regenerated.

Edit 4:

I think this is something related to my deployment on app engine. Looking at deployment log in gradle, WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib were not uploaded. I added

```
   stage { 
    enableJarClasses = true
}
```

but still WEB-INF/lib files are not uploaded.I have different exception thrown on server now as

```
    Uncaught exception from servlet
Class Contact for query has not been resolved. Check the query and any imports/aliases specification
org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotResolvedException: Class Contact for query has not been resolved. Check the query and any imports/aliases specification
at org.datanucleus.query.compiler.JavaQueryCompiler.resolveClass(JavaQueryCompiler.java:906)...
```

Comment: can you please post the whole stacktrace

Comment: Ok...i am solving issues with building the app client with V2 framework and then i will post server call error. (P.S : in case someone interested, migration to V2 can create a lot of errors as Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'...make sure in this case that you updated to android:support 26 or above...discovery after a lot of pain ;(  )

Comment: @MichaelMeyer, answered in edited questions. I have the same issue with all servlet calling EntityManagerFactory and dont have more stacktrace in google console....reference of question to google guys : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/issues/66#issuecomment-335181404